# Fourier Series pointwise convergence

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am doing research and proved to the professor the coefficient of Fourier Series. As you can see from the picture below.

I don't know how to prove the $S_n(x)$ pointwise convergence as $N$ goes to zero. How did he get from equation $(2)$ to $(3)$?

Here is what I know: $S_n$ goes to $f$ if and only if $\sup | S_n(x) - f(x)|$ goes to zero and $x$ belongs to $(-\pi , \pi)$.

[image]

Comment: $$\cos(ny) \cos(nx) + \sin(ny) \sin(nx) = \cos(nx-ny) = \cos(n(x-y)) $$

Comment: How to relate from question 2 and equation below to 3 and 4 and 5. I don't know how and the prove of pointwise convergence of Sn(x) (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from equation (2) to (3) is just playing plug and chug on the definitions that are right there:
$$S_N(x) = \frac 12A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^N A_n\cos nx + B_n\sin nx\\
A_n = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(y)\cos ny\frac{dy}\pi\\B_n = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(y)\sin ny\frac{dy}\pi$$
So (since $\cos 0y = 1$)$$\begin{align}S_N(x)& = \frac12\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(y)\frac{dy}\pi + \sum_{n=1}^N \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(y)\cos ny\frac{dy}\pi\cos nx + \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(y)\sin ny\frac{dy}\pi\sin nx\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\left[1+2\sum_{n=1}^N\cos nx\cos ny+\sin nx\sin ny\right]f(y)\frac{dy}{2\pi}\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\left[1+2\sum_{n=1}^N\cos n(x-y)\right]f(y)\frac{dy}{2\pi}\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi K_N(x-y)f(y)\frac{dy}{2\pi}\end{align}$$
Where $K_N$ is as defined in equation (4).